# Problem with a grid bootstrap and wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have a problem on this page my div.col-4 who is in div.col-9 don' t align.

I explain better with my code and my web page:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-9">

<?php 
    if (have_posts()) {
        while(have_posts()) {

            the_post(); //the_posts() invoque l itétrationde l article en cours
             //the_title() afiche le titre de l article

?>


<div class="col-4 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><?=the_title();?></h5>
            <p>Par <a class="font-weight-bold">La horde</a>, <a class="text-dark"><em style="font-size:12px;">le <?= get_the_date() ?></em></a></p>
            <p class="card-text"><?= the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Lire la suite</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   
<?php           
        }   

    }      

 ?>
    
</div>
```

I have 4 article create in WordPress but on my web page it is appear in vertical align why ?

I show you with a picture of my web page and the render html:

[image: my result web page]

[image: my result html]

Thank s for any help.
Have a nice day.

cedric

Answer (score 0):

`Columns` will not work as needed if no `row` above

As [Bootstrap official site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#how-it-works) said:

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only
> columns may be immediate children of rows.

So you have to add `<div class="row">` below `<div class="col-12 col-lg-9">` however this will not make all `col-4` stay at the same row, since 4*4 = 16 so the last card will go down.

If you wish to put four cards in the same `row` you have to change `col-4` to `col-3` to make the total 12, as [Bootstrap official site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#how-it-works) said:

> Column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of
> the possible **12** per row. So, if you want three equal-width columns
> across, you can use .col-4.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-12 col-lg-9">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-4 mb-4">
         <div class="card">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title"><?=the_title();?></h5>
                 <p>Par <a class="font-weight-bold">La horde</a>, <a class="text-dark"><em style="font-size:12px;">le <?= get_the_date() ?></em></a></p>
                 <p class="card-text"><?= the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Lire la suite</a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-4 mb-4">
         <div class="card">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title"><?=the_title();?></h5>
                 <p>Par <a class="font-weight-bold">La horde</a>, <a class="text-dark"><em style="font-size:12px;">le <?= get_the_date() ?></em></a></p>
                 <p class="card-text"><?= the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Lire la suite</a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-4 mb-4">
         <div class="card">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title"><?=the_title();?></h5>
                 <p>Par <a class="font-weight-bold">La horde</a>, <a class="text-dark"><em style="font-size:12px;">le <?= get_the_date() ?></em></a></p>
                 <p class="card-text"><?= the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Lire la suite</a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-4 mb-4">
         <div class="card">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title"><?=the_title();?></h5>
                 <p>Par <a class="font-weight-bold">La horde</a>, <a class="text-dark"><em style="font-size:12px;">le <?= get_the_date() ?></em></a></p>
                 <p class="card-text"><?= the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Lire la suite</a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First thank' s for your quick answer. I am ok but the problem is the 4 card is on vertical-align(like i show on the pitcure).  Normaly with the code i put they are 3 on horizontal and one behind. I have already try with like you said the second row it do the same comportement(same problem). I really don t understand why it s begin to make me crazy(joke).

Comment: II retry an it work it because i put the row after the_posts(). I had do that to quickly thank a lot @Mhd Alaa Alhaj

Answer (score 0):

I post the correct answer here:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-9">
  <div class="row">
<?php 
    if (have_posts()){
        while( have_posts()){

            the_post(); //the_posts() invoque l itétrationde l article en cours

                        //the_title() afiche le titre de l article

?>


    <div class="col-4 mb-4">
    
        <div class="card">

            <div class="card-body">

                <h5 class="card-title"><?=the_title();?></h5>

                <p>Par <a class="font-weight-bold">La horde</a>, <a class="text-dark"><em style="font-size:12px;">le <?= get_the_date() ?></em></a></p>

                <p class="card-text"><?= the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Lire la suite</a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    
    <?php           

            }   

        }      

    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```